# CIFilter filterWithCVPixelBuffer returning nil in iOS

Tags: ios, camera, core-image, cifilter

I am trying to create a CIFilter using filterWithCVPixelBuffer and it is returning nil.
This is what I'm trying to do:

```
CFDictionaryRef options = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(nil, photo.pixelBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
CIFilter * ciFilter = [CIFilter filterWithCVPixelBuffer:photo.pixelBuffer properties:(__bridge NSDictionary*)options options:nil];
```

photo is an instance of AVCapturePhoto given to the delegate.
I am using iOS 12 and running the code on iPhone7.

Comment: What is the pixel format of your photo?

Comment: Are you sure the photo was captured as RAW? Otherwise `photo.pixelBuffer` would return `nil`.

Comment: @Spads the pixel format is kCVPixelFormatType_14Bayer_RGGB
Actually this is the only raw pixel format available

Comment: @FrankSchlegel yes I am sure that the photo is captured as raw and that photo.pixel buffer is not nil
Actually if I call [CIFilter filterWithImageData:options:] and give it the fileDataRepresentation(which is the dng representation), the code works perfectly fine.

Comment: @RebeccaAbiRaad Have you tried _not_ passing any `properties`?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel yes, I have. It is also returning nil.

Comment: Very strange. Can you maybe try a different route: `CIFilter* ciFilter = [CIFilter filterWithImageData: [photo fileDataRepresentation] options: nil];`

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm currently using. I wanted the path of pixelbuffer for debug reasons and maybe eventually for optimization. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the properties NSDictionary. I should have simply passed photo.metadata.
So the function call would look like:

```
CIFilter * ciFilter = [CIFilter filterWithCVPixelBuffer:photo.pixelBuffer properties:photo.metedata options:nil];
```

Of course, you can pass an `NSDictionary` containing the desired `CIRAWFilterOption(s)`.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I found the answer in the documentation in the header file:

> Returns a CIFilter that will in turn return a properly processed CIImage as "outputImage".
>
> Note that when using this initializer, you should pass in a CVPixelBufferRef with one of the following Raw pixel format types kCVPixelFormatType_14Bayer_GRBG, kCVPixelFormatType_14Bayer_RGGB, kCVPixelFormatType_14Bayer_BGGR, kCVPixelFormatType_14Bayer_GBRG as well as the root properties attachment **from the CMSampleBufferRef**.

So I guess this method should be used when you have a `CMSampleBuffer` and is not feasible when coming from a `AVCapturePhoto`.